# window.print() acts like it will print but does nothing

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'm trying to print a simple document but nothing is being printed. When I click the print button it adds it to the print queue and almost immediately leaves the queue but nothing happens. The printer doesn't even act as if it's about to print. I have a print.css

```
@media print{
  * {
    display: none;
  }

  #preview {
    display: inline;
  }
  #preview input {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and I've added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

to my HTML. It pulls up the print menu and acts like it will print but does nothing. I've never tried this before so I may just be missing a key aspect of this but at the same time it seems right.

Code for the button

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.print()" value="print" />
```

Preview is the div that I am trying to print (I add the innerHTML in a function)

```
<body style="background-color: white; height: 100%; width: 100%" onload="buildForm()">
  <aside id="overlay">
    <section onclick="modal()"></section>
    <div id="preview"></div>
  </aside>
```

Also this is an Electron app if that has anything to do with it. Also yes, the printer does work. I can print from other sources assuming there's content to print.

Due to long amounts of code here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0cxd3su/) to help break it up. **Note** This isn't going to work since it has node modules in the code since it is an Electron app

Comment: This css probably the problem, it hides everything: ` * { display: none; }`.

Comment: @Mottie it hides everything but it should unhide #preview since it is after the *, or is it hiding things that are needed like the stuff in <head>? It still doesn't print even with the * gone

Comment: Inline styles like `<div id="preview" style="display: none"></div>` may not be overridden by css definitions. Try setting that `display:none` in a `@screen{}` media wrapper.

Comment: add `Important` and try

Comment: Remove the `style="display: none"` from the markup and only use CSS as I believe CSS precedence is at issue here.  MOST times forcing the use of `important` means you have some other issues at play that can/should be addressed.

Comment: `<div id="preview" style="display: none"></div>` will hide the preview because it's an embedded style which has the highest importance. perhaps in the style put, `#preview {
    display: inline !important;
  }`

Comment: Just a suggestion but begin to use `<button type="button" onclick="window.print()">print</button>` rather than `<input type="button" onclick="window.print()" value="print" />`

Comment: From comments it appears some other thing is at play here. Please post the  HTML markup and any other CSS.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss it's 400 lines of code so I'm going to break it up in jsfiddle. It's also not going to work since it's an electron app which allows the use of node modules.

Comment: Turns out there's some issues with printing from Electron app so sorry for sending you on a wild goose chase and thanks for trying to help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with Electron since 0.37.x was released while missing the pdf.dll. You can copy it from [0.36.12](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v0.36.12) release and add it to the dist folder. Worked like a charm after that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this change:

HTML

```
<div id="preview"></div>
```

CSS

```
@media screen {
  #preview { display: none; }
}
@media print{
  * {
    display: none;
  }

  #preview {
    display: inline;
  }
  #preview input {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was in the process of typing so +1

Comment: Still didn't fix it. still the same results.

Comment: Honestly, it would be better to not use `* { display: none; }` and instead target elements you want to hide.

Comment: Even without that it's the same results

Comment: Is `#preview` inside another element? Add it as a direct descendant of the `<body>` ([demo](http://jsbin.com/fafogun/1/edit?html,css,output))

Comment: `#preview` is inside an `<aside>` tag. I updated my question with the hierarchy

Comment: I just tried your demo and it worked but when I tried to do it as an electron app it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to unhide all of `#preview` children as well:

```
body * {display: none;}
#preview, #preview * {display: initial !important;}
```

Comment: I thought this was going to be the fix but still nothing. Same results

Comment: @SirParselot Did you make sure to clear your cached CSS after updating? I created a simplified example and was able to get it to print properly. Maybe there is more CSS that is affecting it. Have you tried opening DevTools, and setting the renderer to use the Print media so you can inspect the elements?

Comment: It's an Electron app so there is no cache as far as I know. Also I don't know how to set the renderer to use the Print media

Comment: @SirParselot Open Chrome, open Dev Tools (SHIFT+CTRL/CMD+J), click the vertical ellipses (three dots) at the right of the top menu, choose More Tools..., choose Rendering Settings, enable the "Emulate Print Media" option

Comment: According the print media it should be working just fine. Everything I expect to print is there. I opened an issue with Electron since I think the problem resides there.